# Having issues with scope using Tkinter, for some reason when I print "passw" it remains 0 regardless of checkbutton input

Tags: tkinter

```py
def execute():    
    
     passw = choice2.get()
     print(passw)
          # pdf = Pdf.open(pdfFN, allow_overwriting_input=True)   
          # pdf.save(pdfFN, encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(user= "dog" , owner= "dog")) 
          # pdf.close()
     
     window2.destroy()
    
def createPDF():
      global choice1
      choice1 = IntVar()
      global choice2
      choice2 = IntVar()
      global choice3
      choice3 = StringVar()
      global pdfFN
      filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                           title = "Select a File",
                                           filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                         "*.docx"),
                                                        ("all files",
                                                         "*.*")))
      
    
      label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Selected: " + filename)
      for i in range(len(filename)):
          if(filename[i] == '.'):
              pdfFN = filename[0:i+1] + "pdf"
              break
      convert(filename, pdfFN)   
      
      global window2
      window2 = Tk()
      window2.title('Datasheet Option Panel')
  
      window2_width = 700
      window2_height = 200

      screen2_width = window2.winfo_screenwidth()
      screen2_height = window2.winfo_screenheight()

      center2_x = int(screen2_width/2 - window2_width / 2)
      center2_y = int(screen2_height/2 - window2_height / 2)

      window2.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
      window2.iconbitmap('/software/ablogo.ico')
  
      window2.config(background = "white")   
                        
      Label(window2,
             text = "What would you like to do?",
             width = 80, height = 3,
             fg = "blue").place(x = 70, y = 0 )
           # if(choice1.get()):    
           #     pdf = Pdf.open(pdfFN, allow_overwriting_input=True)   
           #     pdf.save(pdfFN, encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(user="user password", owner="owner password")) 
           #     pdf.close()
      ttk.Checkbutton(window2,
                   text='Password',
                   variable= choice1,
                   onvalue= 1 ,
                   offvalue= 0).place(x = 100, y = 120 )
      ttk.Entry(window2, textvariable = choice3, font = ('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*').place(x = 180, y = 120 )

      ttk.Checkbutton(window2,
                   text='Watermark',
                   variable= choice2,
                   onvalue= 1 ,
                   offvalue= 0).place(x = 440, y = 120 )
      button_submit = Button(window2,
                         text = "Submit", command = execute).place(x=620, y= 160)
       
      window2.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the example code. If you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`, that is likely the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by you doesn't work at all, so it is hard to believe that *Having issues with scope using Tkinter, for some reason when I print "passw" it remains 0 regardless of checkbutton input* is true, but ... I won't discuss it here further.

The code below works with tkinter and Python 3 and does what you wanted it to do. It is still a bit messy and won't run on Python versions using Tkinter unless you change `tkinter` to `Tkinter` and do some other changes to make it run on an older system, but ... just do the small adjustments to the code yourself if necessary to make it run for you and enjoy to see that the values put into the user dialog widgets are printed to the output:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
# pwd = '/'
import os ; pwd = os.popen('pwd').read()

def  convert(filename, pdfFN):
    print('Converting', filename, 'to', pdfFN)    

def execute(): 
     passwYesNo = chckbttn_passw_value.get()    
     wmarkYesNo = chckbttn_wmark_value.get()
     user_entry = user_entry_value.get()     
     print(f'{passwYesNo=}, {wmarkYesNo=}, {user_entry=}')
      # pdf = Pdf.open(pdfFN, allow_overwriting_input=True)   
      # pdf.save(pdfFN, encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(user= "dog" , owner= "dog")) 
      # pdf.close()
     root.destroy()
    
def createPDF():
    global root ; root = Tk()
    root.title('Datasheet Option Panel')
    window_width  = 700 ; screen_width  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    window_height = 200 ; screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    center_x = int(screen_width  / 2 - window_width  / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
    root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
    # root.iconbitmap('/software/ablogo.ico')
    root.config(background = "white")   

    global chckbttn_passw_value ; chckbttn_passw_value = IntVar()
    global chckbttn_wmark_value ; chckbttn_wmark_value = IntVar()
    global user_entry_value     ; user_entry_value     = StringVar()
    global pdfFN
    # """
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = pwd,
        title = "Select a File", 
        filetypes = (("Text files", "*.docx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    for i in range(len(filename)):
        if(filename[i] == '.'):
            pdfFN = filename[0:i+1] + "pdf"
            break
    # """
    # filename = "selectedDocument.docx"   
    # pdfFN    = "selectedDocument.pdf"

    convert(filename, pdfFN)   
            
    label_file_explorer = Label(root, text = "What would you like to do?", 
        width = 68, height = 3, fg = "blue")
    label_file_explorer.place(x = 70, y = 0 )
       # if(choice1.get()):    
       #     pdf = Pdf.open(pdfFN, allow_overwriting_input=True)   
       #     pdf.save(pdfFN, encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(user="user password", owner="owner password")) 
       #     pdf.close()

    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Selected: " + filename)

    ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Password',
        variable=chckbttn_passw_value, 
        onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0).place(x=100,y=120)
    ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Watermark', 
        variable=chckbttn_wmark_value, 
        onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0).place(x=440,y=120)
    ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=user_entry_value,font=('calibre',10,'normal'), 
        show ='*').place(x=180,y=120 )
    
    Button(root, text="Submit", command=execute).place(x=620,y=160)

    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Selected: " + filename)     
    root.mainloop()

createPDF()
```